# Wordpress Camera Plugin how can I hide the post but leave the slideshow?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, camera

I am using a camera slideshow plugin for WordPress the newest version, how can I make it so that I can see the slideshow on front page, but hide the post that duplicates on the main page. I don't want the post to show but just the slideshow. Whenever I am making a post private it hides both the post and the actual slideshow. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I managed to solve this, by hiding the post and using the shortcode in PHP page template like this:

```
<?php echo 
do_shortcode('[camera slideshow="dalaslideshow"]'); ?>
```

But the slideshow should exist in a post before you can call it in PHP.
However, you can hide the post from being shown by making a hidden category and not showing this category on the homepage by filtering.